# AngularJS - How to validate an element directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have created a numberDirective

```
function numberInputDirective()
 {
    return 
    {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: 
        {
            model: '=',
            disabled: '=?',
            decimals: '=?',
            form: '=',
            name: '='
        },
        require: '^form',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'directives/pxNumberInput.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, form) 
        {
              scope.inError = function () 
              {
                  return form.control.$valid; //I need to do something like this    
              }
        }
    }
```

I need to check in the isError function if the value in the control is valid or not

The template is:

```
<input class="input-field form-control" type="number" ng-model="model">
```

The HTML is:

```
 <form role="form" class="form-horizontal psi-keyrates-yieldform psi-keyrates-historical-topcurves" name="SampleControlsForm" novalidate>
      <px-number-input id="objectiveid" name="numericExample"    model="sampleDataModel.numericField" placeholder="Enter numeric value" label="Numeric" required maxlength="10"></px-number-input>
</form>
```

While the form variable tells me if the form (form.$valid) is valid or not, I need to know this particular directive has a valid value or not when the form is submitted. something like this form.control.$valid.

I do not know the name of the control in this directive as it will be set in the html.

I tried: var elem = ctrl.$name + '.' + element.attr('name') + '.$valid';
This returns the string "SampleControlsForm.numericExample.$valid" and if I add a watch on it, it doesn't help nor does scope.$eval.

I'm sure I'm not using it right.

Comment: You shouldn't have to define a template. Create a custom directive that requires ngModel, and add your own validation.

Comment: This is an existing directive that I need to modify. once the directive returns true or false, in the isError method, i need to add an image below it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a custom number validator that shows:

1. How to `require` ngModel so you can access its controller.
2. How to add your own custom validator by adding a property to `$validators` object (angular 1.3 and above). For angular < 1.3, use `ngModelController.$setValidity`
3. How to setup a `$watch` on the `$error` object to insert/remove an image depending on whether the validation passes or fails.
4. How to create a custom directive that works with `ngModel` without needing to define a template.

The `$validators` object allows you to register multiple validation directives for the same `ngModel`.  To add a validator, simply add the validation directive to the same element as `ngModel`.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('myNumber', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    compile: function(element, attr) {
      var img = angular.element('<img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTTyptDmp09eMq1nHtcJHVTAMkKgqdi1ZiGMQSjFeYNApkO92zhCA" />');
           
      return function(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
        function isNumber(n) {
            return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
        }
        
        ngModelCtrl.$validators.mynumber = function(val) {
          return isNumber(val);
        };
        scope.$watch(function() {
          return ngModelCtrl.$error.mynumber;
        }, 
        function(newVal) {
          if (newVal) {
            element.after(img);
          }
          else {
            img.remove();
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <form name="form">
    <input type="text" name="age" my-number ng-model="age" /> {{ age }}
  </form>
  {{ form.age.$error }}
</div>
```

Comment: If anybody finds this in future, please look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-compile- and the stuff just before ```link``` title: 
*returning a (post-link) function - is equivalent to registering the linking function via the link property of the config object when the compile function is empty.* Which means instead of returning function from ```compile``` we can use the same piece of code with ```link``` attribute.